Tangent functor preserves pushouts
Let $\mathcal{Man}$ be a category of $C^\infty$-manifolds over real numbers. On this category there is tangent apace functor $T \colon \mathcal{Man} \to \mathcal{Man}$, sending manifold $A$ to the (total space of) tangent bundle $TA$. Suppose following pushout
\begin{array}
AA & \stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} & B \\
\downarrow{f} & & \downarrow{g} \\
C & \stackrel{k}{\longrightarrow} & D  
\end{array}
exists in $\mathcal{Man}$. Is it true that after applying functor $T$ to the diagram
\begin{array}
ATA & \stackrel{Th}{\longrightarrow} & TB \\
\downarrow{Tf} & & \downarrow{Tg} \\
TC & \stackrel{Tk}{\longrightarrow} & TD  
\end{array}
we still get a pushout diagram?
I've come up with the following argument. If we have maps $TB \to X$ and $TC \to X$ for some manifold $X$ and assume that obvious square is commutative, we can take zero section embedding $Y \to TY$ (which is a natural transformation of functors) for $Y=A,B,C$ thus, getting maps $B \to X$ and $C \to X$ with obvious commutative square. In this way we obtain a map $\phi \colon D \to X$.
To extend this map to the map $TD \to X$ we look at a tangent space $T_d D$, where $d \in D$. Let $a \in A$ be such that $gh(a)=d$, set$b=h(a)$ and $c=f(a)$, then
$$
T_d D = T_b B \oplus T_c C/\sim.
$$
In other words, for a pushout diagram of spaces we get that a tangent space is an upshot of tangent spaces (it seems to be obvious, but is that actually true?). Using this description we can present a tangent vector  at $d \in D$ as pair $(v_B, v_C)$ of tangent vectors (up to equivalence), $v_B \in T_b B$, $v_C \in T_c C$. We send $(v_B, v_C)$ to $Tg(v_B)+Tk(v_C)$. Clearly this map of tangent spaces factors thorough $T_d D = T_b B \oplus T_c C/\sim$. Therefore, we obtain a smooth map $TD \to X$. Looking again at fibers we conclude that any such maps will act in this way on tangent vectors, hence it is unique. Does this argument work? Perhaps there is a reference for this fact.
